# Java8 filter collect both type of value

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to collect both filtered and not filtered value in java 8 filter ?

One way is:

```
.filter( foo -> {
    if(!foo.apply()){
   // add to required collection
    }
    return foo.apply();
  }
```

Is there a better alternative ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 Map<Boolean, List<Foo>> map = 
     collection.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(foo -> foo.isBar());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator with map, so that the function you apply is either the identity for some condition, In below example I calculating square of even numbers and keeping odd numbers as it is.

```
 List<Integer> temp = arrays.stream()
                            .map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i*i : i)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In your case it would be like this :

```
 List<Integer> temp = arrays.stream()
                            .map(!foo.apply() -> ? doSomething: doSomethingElse)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```